# Mongoose .find() method causes requests to hang

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this route defined, but any requests made to it get's stuck on 'pending' and runs forever.

When I log the code, I see `1` followed by `4`, which means the code inside the find method never gets executed

```
  # Calendar routes
  router.get '/calendars', (req, res) ->
    console.log '1'
    Calendar.find (err, calendars) ->
      console.log "2" + err
      console.log "3" + calendars
      res.send(err) if err
      res.json(calendars)
      return
    console.log '4'
    return
```

Model

```
mongoose = require("mongoose")

module.exports = mongoose.model("Calendar",
  name: String
)
```

Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: When a Mongoose callback isn't called, it's typically because that model's connection isn't open. Is your `mongoose.connect` call successful?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: Provide a callback function parameter to your `mongoose.connect` call.

Comment: I dont call mongoose.connect explicitly anywhere

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Until you call `mongoose.connect`, your mongoose queries will simply be queued up.

Add code like this in your startup code to connect:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }    
});
```

In the connection string, replace `test` with the name of your database.