# Stress test / hang test of large Node.JS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, tdd, e2e-testing

We have a large website with express and the whole application is written in Node.JS.

When the mongo db is down our app starts hanging when you refresh the browser on home page and also in other page. This is caused because of the behaviour of the mongoose library when the mongo database goes down. the app is served from ubuntu 14.04 machines.

My question is how to test application "hangs".

What kind of tests should I perform to know that i don't have any more web app hangs. The problem is that a hang can be caused by multiple reasons and not just by the mongoose issue which i have fixed.
How can I test that? 
What kind of tools and techniques are recommended?

Comment: I've never tested for something like that, but it sounds like you could use a headless browser (such as [zombie](http://zombie.js.org/)) for this.

Comment: There must be methodolgies and e2e-tests that can test these issues like performance tests and stress testing.  I wonder if someone already has experience with web "hang" issues testing especially in node.js promise land.

Comment: Is the "hang" a request that just resolves very slowly?

Comment: @SimpleJ - no, the hang resuest doesn't resolve, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331447/mongoose-find-method-causes-requests-to-hang.   But a hang can be caused by multiple issues.