# how can make mongoose fail when executing find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

Hi everyone I'm writing mocha unit tests for my server. How can I get error for mongoose find query. I've tried close the connection before execute but there's nothing firing.

```
User.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // I want to get here
    }
    return done(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following **DO NOT WORK** with mongoose, at least for now *(5.0.17)* :

---

Closing the connection to mongoose is a way to test it, in addition to a proper timeout to set on the `find` request.

```
const request = User.find({});

request.maxTime(1000);

request.exec()
       .then(...)
       .catch(...);
```

or

```
User.find({}, { maxTimeMS: 1000 }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // I want to get here
    }

    return done(result);
});
```

---

**EDIT after further researches** :

---

After trying it myself, it seems that I never get an error from the request.

Changing request `maxTime` or connection parameters `auto_reconnect`, `socketTimeoutMS`, and `connectTimeoutMS` do not seems to have any effect. The request still hang.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331447/mongoose-find-method-causes-requests-to-hang) stack overflow answer saying that all request are queued when mongoose is disconnected from the database. So we won't get any timeout from there.

A soluce I can recommand and that I use on my own project for another reason would be to wrap the mongoose request into a class of my own. So I could check and throw an error myself in case of disconnected database.

Comment: it's not working. There's no error for your code. @grégory-neut

Comment: What connection argument do you have? Especially `auto_reconnect`, `socketTimeoutMS` and `connectTimeoutMS`. Didn't tested but it should totally work

Comment: there's no special arg. for connection. here is my connection setup 'mongoose.connect(url);"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to test your error handling is to use mock. More information in [this previous stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking).

You can mock the mongoose connection and api to drive your test (raise errors...).

Libraries:

- [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org/)
- [testdouble](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like below. Here is the solution.

```
User = sinon.stub(User.prototype, 'find');
User.yields(new Error('An error occured'), undefined);
```

By this code it will return error. @ormaz @grégory-neut Thanks for the help.