# mongoose find on a closed connection not returning any result

Tags: mongoose

myFunc() is triggered every minute by the timer. The find() not executing callback second trigger onwards. I am expecting an error atleast

```
function myFunc() {
    let users = schemaMap.get('users');
    users.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        if(err) logger.error(err);
        logger.info('Mongo users: '+docs);
        mongoose.connection.close();
        //mongoose.disconnect();
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331447/mongoose-find-method-causes-requests-to-hang

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyHK Can mongoose be configured to error out instead-of queue up my query?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose will [queue up collection actions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#callback_never_executes) until the connection is opened.

If you want to disable command buffering:

```
mongoose.set('bufferCommands', false);
```